# JS Script not loading on Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, html

My web page does not seem to load a JS file into it on Firefox, Safari and most mobile browsers, but it works on Chrome (and other chromium based browsers).
https://paxco.in/wallet.html Is the page
I have the script tage `<script type="text/javascript" scr="./js/web3.min.js"></script>` But it does not show in the sources when I use dev tools, and I get errors when I reference functions from the file as according to the browser it is non-existent.

EDIT: Fixed Linking script,
Now I can't reference the /js/web3.min.js file in my other scripts

Comment: check if your script has any errors. Usually chrome alters the dom and ignores certain errors. So check in the console of FF or other browsers if there are any errors

Comment: It's giving `web3 not defined` in the dev tool console.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the element attribute?  `scr` => `src`

Comment: Danyal Imran , Yes I said  get errors when I reference functions from the file as according to the browser it is non-existent. That error is only caused because the ./js/web3.min.js does not load to the browser

Comment: @PaulT. Cheers for that part haha, small mistake we all forget to check for.

Comment: Your error occurs on Vilvaldi in Win10 also, you have an error on your scripts. Ok, I see, you are loading statistics before web3 and in your code somewhere, you attempt to access web3 in statistics before the page was completely load.

Comment: Try to add on your scripts : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: I noticed that you have a mismatch in your opening/closing tags (Firefox marks the closing body tag red, which is an indicator for that). Probably not related to your problem, but still a point you should investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed tag *somewhere* on your page.

This results in the browser not being able to parse the DOM properly, resulting in your script tag not being "rendered".

Chrome has some better error handling for cases like that, which makes it work in that browser.

> [image]

Also, there's a typo:

`scr="./js/web3.min.js"`

Should be

`src="./js/web3.min.js"`